# Magento SQL issue after move to VPS

Tags: mysql, magento

I am getting the error when I try and save a Magento config afjer moving it to another system.

An error occurred while saving this configuration: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer ('magento'@'10.10.1.%') does not exist

I helped move a system from a dedicated VMware environment to a VPS cloud based all in one system.  This included merging the SQL server and the nginx all on to one system and it is all based on Magento.  Not exactly my specialty - VMware is, but all the backend stuff I haven't worked with for years.

So everything is pretty much working, but then after a couple of months, the user says his mail form isn't working.  This is part of Magento, so go into the Mangento admin and contact and just to start with, thought I would toggle the Enable Conctact us off and see if that turned off the form and if I can trace through to what mail server it is trying to use etc. But when I did this and try to save I get the error above.  I google that and found that it seems like the user may not exist after moving.  Is the user it is referencing an SQL user?  I have the old web system that this came from in my lab and I don't see a Magento Linux user.  I exported and and imported all the databases from the old MySQL server.  Any ideas on what I need to look for here, I would really appreciate as I said, not my specialty, but it got tagged on to a job I was doing and I would like to finish it up.

Thanks
Bill

Comment: ok, have been working on this more.  So this used to be on a private network 10.10.1 as I recall.  Now it is on a public network running all on the same system.  I think I need to change the user from ('magento'@'10.10.1.%')  to magento@localhost or else magento@myipnumber.  But I do not know how to do this in Magento.  The user magento@localhost exists and has all the privilege it needs, but I just need to tell magento to use that user.  help...

Comment: seenm to have managed to grant permissions to that user and it is now allowing me to save configurations etc...  now on to the next problem

Comment: It is a MySQL server admin issue, aside from manual edit of local.xml to give database access credentials, this has to be taken care of through MySQL or cPanel.